# question on uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,10]$  and zero elsewhere  and let $Y$ be another random variable uniformly distributed on $[0, 20]$  and zero elsewhere. Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, find

a.  $\mathbb{P}(X<4 \cap Y<8)$

b.  $\mathbb{E} [X + Y]$

c.  $\mathbb{E} [XY]$

d.  $\operatorname{Var}(X + Y)$

My work: we will have to double integrate from $0$ to $4$ in $x$ and $0$ to $8$ in $y$, but I am not able to find the function to integrate.

I don't know if this makes sense, please help me with these.

Comment: @dr.ivanova - The tag you have inserted is incorrect. Probability-theory should not be in this question.

Comment: @dr.ivanova, the interval $0<x<10$ is usually denoted by $(0,10)$; the interval $0\le x\le 10$ is usually denoted by $[0,10]$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is uniformly distributed in $(0, 10)$, then $f_{X}(x) = $ ?.

If $Y$ is uniformly distributed in $(0, 20)$, then $f_{Y}(y) = $ ?.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = $ ?.

Comment: fX(x)= 1/10 for 0<x<10 


fY(y) 1/20 for 0<y<20

 
fX,Y(x,y) = fX*fY=1/200 for 0<x,y<10

right?

Comment: @rohit: Good. Now integrate that as you stated above in the question.

Comment: @rohit - Technically, $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = \dfrac{1}{200}$ for $0 < x < 10$ and $0 < y < 20$. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: ok cool i got it...i got answer for first part as 4/25. Is that right? How about rest of them?

Comment: 4/25 is correct. For part b - use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]$. For part c - since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, what do you know about $\mathbb{E}[XY]$? d uses independence as well.

Comment: E[XY] = E[X] E[Y] and same with part d. But how to find E[X] and Var[Y] here in this case?

Comment: @rohit - Two ways you can compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$: use $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int\limits_{0}^{10}xf_{X}(x)\text{ d}x$ or use a formula for it (which I would imagine you should have been taught). To compute $\text{Var}(Y)$, use $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] - (\mathbb{E}[Y])^{2}$. You should know how to compute these expectations using integration.